# Sequences of Functions: Looking for a sequence $(x_n) $ on $[0,1]$ such that the sequence $(x_{n}^n)\neq0$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

So, I have this problem on my analysis homework. We've been looking at sequences of functions.  In particular, we are looking at $x^n$ and the question asks us to show that there is a sequence of values of $x$ on $[0,1]$, call it $(x_n)$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_{n}^n) \neq 0 = lim_{n\to\infty} x^n$ on $[0,1]$. Just to be sure we're on the same page, I'm using $(x_n)$ to signify the infinite sequence rather than $\{x_n\}$ which would just be the list of values taken (which could be infinite, I suppose but need not be).

Any hints? Thanks.

EDIT: I took out the extraneous = 0.

Comment: Is it $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^n \neq 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, you haven't said what the value $x$ is so I don't know why you include $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n=0$. Take $x_n=2^{-\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: Take for example $x_n=1-\frac1n$.  Then, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n^n=e^{-1}\ne 0$

Comment: Someguy, $x_n$ is the general term of an arbitrary sequence of values of x on the domain [0,1]. 

Henry W, no, it's the limit of a sequence of functions evaluated on points in a sequence on [0,1] on the left side, and the point-wise limit of the sequence of functions on the right. 

This whole topic of sequences of functions is mental.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $x_n=1-\frac an$ gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^n=e^{-a}
$$
For $a\in(0,1)$, the sequence is in $(0,1)$

---

On the other hand, if
$$
0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\lt1
$$
Then for some $N$, if $n\ge N$,
$$
0\le x_n\le\frac{x+1}2=1-\frac{1-x}2
$$
and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^n
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1-x}2\right)^n\\
&\le \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\frac{1-x}2n}\\[3pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Like my comment ... ;-))

Comment: Ah, indeed it was. I edited about the same time as your comment.

Comment: It's possible that the OP is actually asking whether there is a sequence $x_n\in [0,1]$ for which $\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=x<1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n^n\ne 0$.

Comment: If so, the question should be modified to mention $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$.

Comment: I agree that the question is ambiguously stated.  But having had another look, the OP wrote "$\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_{n}^n) \neq 0 = lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = 0$," and I drew inference from the appearance of the latter limit.  I believe that the "$x$" in that limit is the limit of the sequence $x_n$.  -Mark

Comment: I have added an answer to the alternate interpretation

Comment: When uncertain between a comment and an answer,  I alwsys choose answer. Easier to format and more points.

Comment: I suppose the only constraint on what x converges to is that when it is applied to the sequence of functions, it has a non-zero limit. Whereas the point-wise limit of this sequence of functions is zero.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting sequence is $x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$, where $r$ is a parameter that can be varied from $0$ to $4$.
If $0 < r < 1$, clearly the sequence will converge to $0$ and with $1 <r  < 3$, $x_n$ converges to $1 - 1/r$.

But the terms of sequence will "bifurcate" for $r>3$. ultimately leading to chaotic behavior at values greater than about $3.44949$. For more, look up "logistic maps" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map.

Comment: Wellcome to MSE I hope that you will obtain good feedback about question and write an good answer

Comment: Thanks Alphago.  

TJ, this is cool. I am actually quite interested in this concept and will mess around with this sequence on my own time.